# Mysql execute data. What separator to choose for a string, further to explode to create an array?

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL query is

```
SELECT CompanyName, RegistrationNumber, VatCode 
FROM 18_6_TransactionPartners 
WHERE (CompanyName = ? OR RegistrationNumber = ? OR VatCode = ?)
```

`?` replace with `$data_show_existing_records`. But initially `$data_show_existing_records` is in form of string (user input).

At first decided to create such `$data_show_existing_records = $data_show_existing_records. $data_a[$i]. ','. $data_b[$i]. ','. $data_d[$i]. ',';` (this is created within foreach, because `$i` may be only 0, but may also be 100)

And convert to array in such way

```
$data_show_existing_records = substr($data_show_existing_records, 0, -1);

$data_show_existing_records = explode(",", $data_show_existing_records);
```

But for example for `CompanyName` user may input `My, company` or leave some input empty.

In such case I will get error `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`. Because there would be more `$data` in array than `?`.

Then decided replace `,` with `|` (because suppose `|` is less used than `,`).

But this seems not good solution. What would be better (what to use as string/user input separator)? May be just need to escape `,` (but how)? Please, advice

**Update**
Found solution for empty input: `$data_show_existing_records = $data_show_existing_records. "$data_a[$i]". ','. "$data_b[$i]". ','. "$data_d[$i]". ',';`

But what to do with `,`?

**Next update**

Create initial query(shortened code) and data for the query

```
foreach ($num_row_1 as $i => $row) {//$num_row_1 is number of rows in user input
$query_to_show = $query_to_show. 'WHERE (CompanyName = ? OR RegistrationNumber = ? OR VatCode = ?) ';
$data_show_existing_records = $data_show_existing_records. "$data_a[$i]". '"|"'. "$data_b[$i]". '"|"'. "$data_d[$i]". '"|"';
}
```

Get for example:

`$query_to_show =`

`WHERE (CompanyName = ? OR RegistrationNumber = ? OR VatCode = ?) OR (CompanyName = ? OR RegistrationNumber = ? OR VatCode = ?)`

and

`$data_show_existing_records =`

`first name"|"123"|"112233"|"second name"|"456"|"445566"|"`

Then convert to array

```
$data_show_existing_records = substr($data_show_existing_records, 0, -1);
$data_show_existing_records = explode('"|"', $data_show_existing_records);
```

And then final query

```
$query_show_existing_records = "
SELECT CompanyName, RegistrationNumber, VatCode 
FROM 18_6_TransactionPartners 
$query_to_show
";
```

And prepare/execute

```
$sql_show_existing_records = $db->prepare($query_show_existing_records);
$sql_show_existing_records->execute($data_show_existing_records);
$data_show_existing_records1 = $sql_show_existing_records->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

**Solution**

Changed preparation for query and data to following:

```
$flag = 0;//Set as WHERE
$data_show_existing_records = array();

foreach ($num_row_1 as $i => $row) {

if($flag == 0) {
$query_to_show = $query_to_show. 'WHERE (CompanyName = ? OR RegistrationNumber = ? OR VatCode = ?) ';
$flag = 1;
}
else {
$query_to_show = $query_to_show. 'OR (CompanyName = ? OR RegistrationNumber = ? OR VatCode = ?) ';
}

$data_show_existing_records[] = $data_a[$i];
$data_show_existing_records[] = $data_b[$i];
$data_show_existing_records[] = $data_d[$i];

}
```

Comment: if the real problem is only the user data containing the string used to explode, you can escape that particular character before adding them to the array

Comment: Yes, the only problem is user data containing the string. How to escape? Hmm, but I `SELECT` to check if in MySQL exists user's input. If I modify user's input, I could not compare....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens` means that you supplied more variables than there are `?` that can be bound to them. Looking at your code and explanation, you are making a comma seperated list that can contain 3 values, but can also contain 300 values if it happens to contain 100 rows.

To answer your question: *Choose a character, or a serie of characters as seperator that cannot be in the data. Choosing a seperator that is in the data, or 'unlikely' in the data can cause a security issue.*

In your specific situation, there is no reason to transform the data to a comma seperated string, then explode it again into an array. Just add it directly to your final format (most likely a 2-dimensional array if you want to perform multiple queries):

```
$output = Array();
for( $i = 0; $i < count( $data_a ); $i++ ) {
  $output[] = Array( $data_a[$i], $data_b[$i], $data_d[$i] );
}

/*** var_dump( $output );
   * Array(
   *   Array( 1, 2, 3 ),
   *   Array( 4, 5, 6 ),
   *   Array( 7, 8, 9 ), etc...
   * );
 ***/

foreach( $output as $k => $row ) {
  /*** Do your query
     * $row contains 3 values for this query; next loop it contains the next 3 values
   ***/
}
```

Comment: As understand then with `foreach( $output as $k => $row ) {` I get for example 100 times `SELECT WHERE`. Suppose this will use more resources than one `SELECT WHERE OR OR OR`?

Comment: Well, that's how you set up your query in the question? I am not sure if it is possible to use `param IN ("1","2","3","a","Evil, string, is evil")` in prepared queries and even after reading your question several times, I can't figure out if that is what you actually want.

Comment: Yes, just need to write query and data in a way that need to be executed one time. I will update question with solution